# JavaFX Scene builder. how to get value from a Slider?

Tags: slider, scenebuilder

Good evening, gentleman's.

I am learning to use Scene Builder to create a GUI from scratch, which means i did not create any object at main class; the Scene Builder itself created everything at the FXML file.

So, in this window of mine i have two sliders and a start button, who will require the int values of both sliders to run.

start method would be like

```
public void start(slider1 int value, slider2 int value){ code }
```

Sliders in the fxml file, they have a id:

```
<Slider fx:id="escritoresQuant" blockIncrement="1.0" layoutX="85.0" layoutY="314.0" majorTickUnit="1.0" max="4.0" minorTickCount="0" prefHeight="14.0" prefWidth="71.0" showTickLabels="true" showTickMarks="true" snapToTicks="true" />
  <Slider fx:id="leitoresQuant" blockIncrement="1.0" layoutX="85.0" layoutY="349.0" majorTickUnit="1.0" max="6.0" minorTickCount="0" prefHeight="14.0" prefWidth="71.0" showTickLabels="true" showTickMarks="true" snapToTicks="true" />
```

How can i get int value from both those sliders?
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set an eventListener for when the user changes the slider, if you haven't already. 
onMouseReleased="#onSliderChanged"

```
//in the FXML
<Slider  fx:id="escritoresQuant" blockIncrement="1.0" majorTickUnit="5.0" 
max="26.0" min="-26.0" 
minorTickCount="1"  onMouseReleased="#onSliderChanged"
prefHeight="38.0" prefWidth="287.0" showTickLabels="true" 
showTickMarks="true" snapToTicks="true"
style="-fx-background-color: white;" value="3.0" 
BorderPane.alignment="BOTTOM_CENTER" />


//in the Controller class
@FXML
private Slider escritoresQuant;

@FXML
public void onSliderChanged() {
    int sliderValue = (int) escritoresQuant.getValue();
    System.out.println(sliderValue + " ");
    txtOut.setText(escritoresQuant.getValue()+" ");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that [this is what you are looking for](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Slider.html#getValue--).

You should be able to get the value as a `double` by calling `escritoresQuant.getValue()`